# Get php variable from url on reload without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables, url

I'm working on a hobby project (usually working as a designer, so not all that familiar to php – please have oversight with all or any redundant code), trying to learn new things. Now I've bumped into a problem that I don't quite seem to get the hang of.
I have an index.php used to display random sentences from data.php, this works fine – however I want to be able to sort out specific types of sentences for different people if necessary. This is done with a dropdown containing Designer, Illustrator and Developer.

If for example you choose Developer from the dropdown menu, the page reloads with `index.php?yrke=developer` in the URL as a result. This is all fine and as expected, and when i echo `$_GET['yrke'];` from data.php it displays the text "developer" fine the first load, but upon clicking the `randomizerButton` button (note that the content is loaded from data.php without refreshing the page in the browser when clicking this button) `$_GET['yrke'];` does not seem to be able to get a read on the value in the url (putting `$_GET['yrke'];` in `index.php` obviously works regardless, but I need to access the url variable in data.php).

If there's a way to do this while maintaining the "update-content-without-browser-refresh" function that'd be awesome, the other easiest solution would perhaps be to remove said "update-content-without-browser-refresh" and go for good old refreshes and thus solving the problem – *but why make it that easy right?*

**index.php** *(excerpt)*

```
<button data-href="data.php" class="randomizerButton">Randomize sentences</button>

<form action="index.php" method="get">
    <select name="yrke" onchange="this.form.submit()">

        <option value="designer"<?=$_GET['yrke'] == 'designer' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>Designer</option>
        <option value="illustrator"<?=$_GET['yrke'] == 'illustrator' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>Illustrator</option>
        <option value="developer"<?=$_GET['yrke'] == 'developer' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>Developer</option>

    </select>
</form>

<?php include('data.php'); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('button.randomizerButton').click(function(){
                scriptUrl = $(this).attr('data-href');
                $.post(scriptUrl, function(response){
                    $('#results').html(response);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**data.php** *(excerpt)*

```
    echo $_GET['yrke'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `$_GET['yrke']` on `data.php` you would have to use `$.get()` and just use the full URL, like:

```
$.get('data.php?yrke='+encodeURIComponent($('[name=yrke]').val()), function(response){
  $('#results').html(response);
}
```

I would use

```
$.post('data.php', {yrke:encodeURIComponent($('[name=yrke]').val())}, function(response){
  $('#results').html(response);
}
```

with `$_POST['yrke']` on `data.php`. Usually, I would not have a form that submits in the traditional manner. It's all about the AJAX.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So using `$_POST['yrke']` would be beneficial in this case mainly in combination with AJAX, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but you could do something like this...

```
        <div id ="content">

        <?php
        $pages_dir ='pages';
        if(!empty($_GET['p'])){

            $pages =scandir($pages_dir, 0);
            unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);

            $p = $_GET['p'];

            if (in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)){
            include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');
            }else {
                echo'Page not found';
            }

            }else{
                include($pages_dir.'/home.inc.php');

            }

        ?>
HERE
        </div>
```

Make a folder called pages then name the files within the folder "aboutus.inc.php" ect. the important part of the file extension is .inc.php , you can name anything before .inc.php anthing you like here is an example of how to write the navigation "About us"

IF need be I can send you a blank template